# How to get parent usb device info using Python?

Tags: python

Can someone please tell how to get a usb device’s parent information in Python?

I tried WMI, win32com, and pyusb without any lucks.

Thanks!

Comment: What specifically did you try and why didn't those options work?

Comment: What errors did you encounter with Pywin32?

Answer (score 0):

The usb device has a child device com-port. I can find the child device info using serial.tools.list_ports.comports(). From the tool usbtreeview.exe, I can see the child device has a parent with class type usb. How do I retrieve the parent’s info using Python?